# Run scrapy using subprocess

Tags: python, scrapy, subprocess

I need to run several python script's, some of those are scrapy projects.

To run a spider I try this:

```
from subprocess import call
import subprocess

call(["scrapy",'crawl','my_spider','-o output_file.csv'],cwd='/home/luis/Schreibtisch/kukun/bbb_new_pro/scripts/2_Get_links)
```

I wonder whether is posible to specify the output's file directory,  I tried this:

```
call(["scrapy",'crawl','my_spider','-o folder_1/folder_2/output_file.csv'],cwd='project_folder')
```

But that only creates a new folders under the project directory I want the file outside tht folder.

The other thing is, Can I specify the name of the ouput file  in a variable? something like:

```
file_name = 'output file.csv'

 call(["scrapy",'crawl','my_spider','-o + file_name '],cwd='project_folder')
```

Comment: add `/` to the beginning of your output folder

Comment: @eLRuLL I try that too, didn't work.

Comment: As @eLRull suggests, `call(["scrapy",'crawl','my_spider','-o /absolute/path/to/folder_1/folder_2/output_file.csv'],cwd='project_folder')` should work. For the other case, maybe `call(["scrapy",'crawl','my_spider','-o %s' % file_name],cwd='project_folder')` is what you want. Note that running spiders from a script like that is not the recommended way ; read the [docs section about using CrawlProcess](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) for this

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
from subprocess import call

name = "spider_name"
call(["scrapy", "crawl", "{0}".format(name), "-o {0}.json".format(name)])
```